# Boolean equal to -1

Tags: python, boolean

A rookie question probably..I am reading [some code](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/example/kaggle-ndsb2/Preprocessing.py) and wondering about line 28:

```
if len(files) == 0 or not files[0].endswith(".dcm") or root.find("sax") == -1:
    continue
```

So why does the boolean operation on the left hand side equal -1 (instead of 0)?

Comment: `==` is a truthy comparison. It is not seeing if that's a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

`str.find()` returns `-1` if the provided text is not found, `root.find("sax") == -1` is checking for that.

The line might be a little more readable if it were:

```
if not files or files[0].endswith('dcm') or 'sax' not in root:
```

Comment: Okay, I forgot this. Thanks a lot Will.

Answer (score 1):

according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20find#str.find

str.find(sub[, start[, end]])
Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found within the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. **Return -1 if sub is not found**.

Comment: Thank you for your help.